# Composer update not working since installing SSL certificate

Tags: git, ssl, composer-php

I installed an SSL certificate on my Ubuntu 16.04 server and since then composer has stopped working correctly.

The certificate works correctly when accessing the website through a browser. However, when running `sudo composer update`, I get the following warning:

> The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo` failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
>   failed to open stream: `php_network_getaddresses`: `getaddrinfo` failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
>   https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

And then the following error:

```
 Updating dependencies (including `require-dev`)
  - Updating soundasleep/html2text (0.2.2 => 0.3.4)
    Checking out a1f77b8f340c8425b746bef1d1040189e89be334
    Update failed (Failed to clone https://github.com/soundasleep/html2text.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.
>
- https://github.com/soundasleep/html2text.git
  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/soundasleep/html2text.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
>
- git@github.com:soundasleep/html2text.git
  ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
)
    `Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]?`
```

If I try to reinstall it, it returns the following:

```
- Removing soundasleep/html2text (0.2.2)
- Installing soundasleep/html2text (0.3.4)
    Cloning a1f77b8f340c8425b746bef1d1040189e89be334
    Failed to download soundasleep/html2text from source: Failed to clone https://github.com/soundasleep/html2text.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.

- https://github.com/soundasleep/html2text.git
  Cloning into '/path/to/dir/vendor/soundasleep/html2text'...
  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/soundasleep/html2text.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com

- git@github.com:soundasleep/html2text.git
  Cloning into '/path/to/dir/vendor/soundasleep/html2text'...
  ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.

    Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing soundasleep/html2text (0.3.4)
    Downloading: 100%
    Downloading: 100%
    Downloading: 100%

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://api.github.com/repos/soundasleep/html2text/zipball/a1f77b8f340
  c8425b746bef1d1040189e89be334" file could not be downloaded: php_network_ge
  taddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

`sudo composer diagnose` returns this:

```
Checking http connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed`: Temporary failure in name resolution
failed to open stream: `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo` failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
```

I already tried `export http_proxy=myexternalip:80` and `export https_proxy=myexternalip:443` (as well as `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` but with no luck.

Comment: I highly doubt that installing the SSL cert (in your web server?) and the error you’re seeing are correlated. The Composer errors come from the network not working properly. Can you try `curl https://packagist.org/packages.json` or `wget https://packagist.org/packages.json` and if that fails add the error message?

Comment: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: packagist.org`

Comment: I’m like 99.9% sure that this has nothing to do with the SSL cert. Can you try `ping 87.98.253.214` (the IP of packagist.org).

Comment: `PING 87.98.253.214 (87.98.253.214) 56(84) bytes of data.` `64 bytes from 87.98.253.214: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=5.38 ms` etc. Pinging fine

Comment: So the problem apparently is name resolution. Can you check if `host packagist.org` works and post the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: `connection timed out; no servers could be reached`. The file `resolv.conf` does not seem to exist, it appears red in the directory list (`resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` and the latter does not exist in that directory) and is empty when I `nano` it.

Comment: So name resolution is really broken. Which distro are you using? Try to create `/etc/resolv.conf` with `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in it.

Comment: That fixed the issue :) I am using Ubuntu 16.04 by the way. Will the change to the `resolv.conf` file get overwritten by any Ubuntu or Apache updates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126018/discussion-between-andreas-wolf-and-pawel).

Comment: The name server solves my problems. Thank @AndreasWolf